# How to format the data in a table to have only numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

This question is in continuation of my earlier query, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43568/3066. I am able to store the output of my function in a table, however the table consists of various brackets and variable headings which I do not require. A clean table with only values in two columns will help me to further evaluate the table.

I have many such codes, resulting in about 15 tables each containing 600 rows of data. A easy way to have the table in required format as above will help me avoid lot of formatting.

Further the code as below also gives 2 values for a single input value. I will like both the values to be given in two separate rows.

The code is as given below. Request for help to solve this.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
Clear[A, r, v, u, p, γ , ug, Nx, Ny, Nz, EM]
x = 2 r Cos[v + u + γ] - r Cos [(2 v) + u + γ]
Nxu = D[x, u]
Nxv = D[x, v]
Nx = Nxu Nxv

y = 2 r Sin[v + u + γ] - r  Sin[(2 v) + u + γ]
Nyu = D[y, u]
Nyv = D[y, v]
Ny = Nyu Nyv

z = p u
Nzu = D[z, u]
Nzv = D[z, v]
Nz = Nzu Nzv

re = 27.5
r = 16.5
g = ArcCos[((5 r^2) - (re^2))/(4 r^2)]
p = 108/(2 π)
γ = 45 ° 2 Pi / 360
A = 50 + r
γc = 46 ° 2 Pi / 360

EM [u_, v_] = Simplify[(A - x + p Cot[γc]) Nz + (A Cot[γc]) Ny + z Nx ]
ug[thet_] := With[{u = thet}, NSolve[EM[u, v] == 0 && 0 <= v <= g, v, Reals]]

myTable = Map[{#, ug[#]} &, Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1]]

Export["coordinatesM13.xls", myTable]
```

The output for the table is currently as below:

```
{{0., {}}, 
 {0.1, {}}, 
 {0.2, {}}, 
 {0.3, {}}, 
 {0.4, {}}, 
 {0.5, {}}, 
 {0.6, {}}, 
 {0.7, {}}, 
 {0.8, {}}, 
 {0.9, {}}, 
 {1., {}}, 
 {1.1, {}}, 
 {1.2, {{v -> 0.877726}}}, 
 {1.3, {{v -> 0.757594}}}, 
 {1.4, {{v -> 0.616049}}},
 {1.5, {{v -> 1.48929*10^-17}, {v -> 0.418666}}}, 
 {1.6, {}}, 
 {1.7, {{v -> 4.32695*10^-17}, {v -> 0.94549}}}, 
 {1.8, {{v -> 9.4028*10^-17}, {v -> 0.879002}}}, 
 {1.9, {{v -> 1.4318*10^-16}, {v -> 0.812557}}}, 
 {2., {{v -> 1.94556*10^-16}, {v -> 0.746152}}}, 
 {2.1, {{v -> 2.50387*10^-16}, {v -> 0.679788}}}, 
 {2.2, {{v -> 3.13018*10^-16}, {v -> 0.613464}}}, 
 {2.3, {{v -> 3.85566*10^-16}, {v -> 0.54718}}}, 
 {2.4, {{v -> 4.72647*10^-16}, {v -> 0.480935}}}, 
 {2.5, {{v -> 5.8166*10^-16}, {v -> 0.414731}}}, 
 {2.6, {{v -> 7.25488*10^-16}, {v -> 0.348566}}}, 
 {2.7, {{v -> 9.28936*10^-16}, {v -> 0.282443}}}, 
 {2.8, {{v -> 1.24694*10^-15}, {v -> 0.216362}}}, 
 {2.9, {{v -> 1.83073*10^-15}, {v -> 0.150324}}}, 
 {3., {{v -> 3.30427*10^-15}, {v -> 0.0843294}}}, 
 {3.1, {{v -> 1.52413*10^-14}, {v -> 0.0183812}}}, 
 {3.2, {}}, 
 {3.3, {}}, 
 {3.4, {}}, 
 {3.5, {}}, 
 {3.6, {}}, 
 {3.7, {}}, 
 {3.8, {}}, 
 {3.9, {}}, 
 {4., {}}, 
 {4.1, {}}, 
 {4.2, {}}, 
 {4.3, {{v -> 0.944253}}}, 
 {4.4, {{v -> 0.828585}}}, 
 {4.5, {{v -> 0.697065}}}, 
 {4.6, {{v -> 2.7593*10^-17}, {v -> 0.531873}}}, 
 {4.7, {{v -> 0.0583604}, {v -> 0.125963}}}, 
 {4.8, {{v -> 0.960336}}}, 
 {4.9, {{v -> 5.11674*10^-17}, {v -> 0.894928}}}, 
 {5., {{v -> 1.088*10^-16}, {v -> 0.829509}}}, 
 {5.1, {{v -> 1.63611*10^-16}, {v -> 0.764084}}}, 
 {5.2, {{v -> 2.20467*10^-16}, {v -> 0.698659}}}, 
 {5.3, {{v -> 2.82376*10^-16}, {v -> 0.633237}}}, 
 {5.4, {{v -> 3.5243*10^-16}, {v -> 0.567823}}}, 
 {5.5, {{v -> 4.34721*10^-16}, {v -> 0.502421}}}, 
 {5.6, {{v -> 5.35437*10^-16}, {v -> 0.437036}}}, 
 {5.7, {{v -> 6.64873*10^-16}, {v -> 0.37167}}}, 
 {5.8, {{v -> 8.41904*10^-16}, {v -> 0.306328}}}, 
 {5.9, {{v -> 1.10567*10^-15}, {v -> 0.241014}}}, 
 {6., {{v -> 1.5532*10^-15}, {v -> 0.175731}}}, 
 {6.1, {{v -> 2.51035*10^-15}, {v -> 0.110485}}}, 
 {6.2, {{v -> 6.17841*10^-15}, {v -> 0.0452779}}}}
```

Comment: Please format your question, have a look at the [markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: This is your third question. By now you should have noticed that we like to see properly formatted code on this site. Just dumping code and data into your question is not the way to attract answers.

Comment: Seems like a job for `Part` where you can extract whatever parts of your list you wish.

Comment: In your current output, whenever you have two rules for `v`, the first rule is suspiciously close to zero. Do you really want all those different approximations to zero? Or should be chopped to zero? Or simply removed? You really need to show us how you want your final output to look.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
myTable = Map[{#, (v /. Last[ug[#]]) /. v->Indeterminate} &, Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1]]
```

Comment: many thanks @Ymareth, I am able to get the required. Thanks for helping me save lot of formatting time

Comment: @kamalagrawal If the answer fits your needs you can accept it with a mark below the score. Please, take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)