# Extracting integers from a Dataset containing variables

Tags: dataset, vector, map, table

I want to extract two vectors DataA = {1,0,0,0} and DataB = {0,2,5,0} from a dataset. I tried a few ways including using the `dataset` and `map` function like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43584/how-to-format-the-data-in-a-table-to-have-only-numbers) but I'm afraid I'm a bit stuck. Specifically, I need to get rid of the assignment variables before generating the dataset. This way I can use a clean dataset to call `A` and `B` like below

```
data = {{{A -> 1, B -> 0}}, {{A -> 0, B -> 2}}, {{A -> 0, 
     B -> 5}}, {{A -> 0, B -> 0}}, {{A -> 0, B -> 0}}}; 

data = Dataset[data] 
DataA = data[[1 ;; 5, "A"]] (*A vector with all A values*) 
DataB = data[[1 ;; 5, "B"]] (*A vector with all B values*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
data2 = Association /@ Flatten /@ data;
```

To display `A` and `B` as columns you must use string keys:

```
data3 = KeyMap[ToString] /@ data2;

data3 // Dataset
```

[image]

```
Lookup[data3, "A"]
```

{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Comment: I think A has to be a column header, so this may not work to generate a vector. Each row here belongs to a "set" .

Comment: Like the revised answer?

Comment: Yes. I used DataA = Normal[data3[[1 ;; 6, "A"]]] for the final stretch

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {{{A -> 1, B -> 0}}, {{A -> 0, B -> 2}}, {{A -> 0, 
     B -> 5}}, {{A -> 0, B -> 0}}, {{A -> 0, B -> 0}}};

dataA = Flatten[data, 1][[All, 1]][[All, 2]]
```

> {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

```
dataB = Flatten[data, 1][[All, 2]][[All, 2]]
```

> {0, 2, 5, 0, 0}